# Neo4J / Cypher Query very slow with order by property

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a graph database with 5M of nodes and 10M of relationships.
I'm on a Macbook Pro with 4GB RAM. I have already try to adjust java heap size and neo4j memory without success.

My problem is that i have a simply cypher query like that :

```
MATCH (pet:Pet {id:52163})-[r:FOLLOWS]->(friend) 
MATCH (friend)-[r:POSTED]->(n) 
RETURN friend.id, TYPE(r),LABELS(n),n.id
LIMIT 30;
```

This query takes 100ms , which is impressive. But when i add an "ORDER BY" this query takes a long time => 8s :/

```
MATCH (pet:Pet {id:52163})-[r:FOLLOWS]->(friend) 
MATCH (friend)-[r:POSTED]->(n) 
RETURN friend.id, TYPE(r),LABELS(n),n.id
ORDER BY r.date DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

Does Someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider [relationship indexes](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing-relationships.html) to speed up your query. The date property could be indexed this way. You're using the `ORDER BY` keyword which will almost always make your query slower as it needs to iterate the entire result set to perform the ordering.

Also consider using a single `MATCH` statement if that suits your needs:

```
MATCH (pet:Pet {id:52163})-[r:FOLLOWS]->(friend)-[r:POSTED]->(n)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer !

I reimported my database with the Michael Hunger's batch-importer, with node_auto_index and relationship_auto_index on `date` property.

Everything seems to be ok with these indexes, all the relations with the date property are indexed.

But the query is still too long ... Nothing has changed